# Undefined method 'errors' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following [this tutorial on authentication in rails](http://www.sitepoint.com/rails-userpassword-authentication-from-scratch-part-i/) and I'm encountering an issue on the html signup form :

> undefined method `errors` for `nil:NilClass`

to this line : `<% if @user.errors.any? %>`.

I searched a lot on internet and tried a lot of things, but I cannot make it work.

Here is my view :

```
<%= form_for(:user, :url => {:controller => 'users', :action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
  <input class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4" type="text" placeholder="Email" size="6"></br>
  <input class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4" type="password" placeholder="Password" size="6"></br>
  <input class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4" type="password" placeholder="Password confirmation" size="6"></br>
  <%= f.submit %><div id="valid"><input class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4" type="submit" value="Sign up"/></div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-link col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4"><%=link_to "Already registered ?", home_path%></button>
<% end %>
<% if @user.errors.any? %> // The error line 
  <ul class="Signup_Errors">
  <% for message_error in @user.errors.full_messages %>
    <li>* <%= message_error %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

My controller :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice] = "You signed up successfully"
      flash[:color]= "valid"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Form is invalid"
      flash[:color]= "invalid"
    end
    render "new"
  end
end
```

and my route :

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root :to => 'users#home'
  get 'home' => 'users#home'
  get 'signup' => 'users#signup'

  resources :users do
    post :create
  end
```

Comment: There's no `@user` value It's not clear how you're displaying that page, but apparently the `new` action isn't being run.

Comment: There is a link on my home page (sign in) to reach the sign up page.

Comment: So, that will run the non-existing `signup` method, which Rails uses as a way to find the view. There's no `@user` value, it's `nil`, so the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rename the `new` action to `signup`. 
In current state - rails sees the template for `signup` and assumes that corresponding controller action is just empty, thus the `nil` in instance variable, because `new` is not being called.